# Put a devexpress dbgridview cell's contents with different textformats

Tags: delphi, devexpress

With Devexpress cxGrid, I've a tablegridview showing a db table of three fields of varchar(30); ID, NAME and DESCRIPTION

Actual cxgrid appearance :
`ID        NAME        DESCRIPTION
1         Name 1      Description 1
2         Name 2      Description 2
.         ...         ...
X         Name X      Description 3`

and, i want the two fields to be concatenated and separated by #13 (in two lines), and each line with a special text format (ex. the 1st with bold and the 2nd with italic).

The cxgrid's appearance I look for :
`ID        NAME and DESCRIPTION (just one field instead of two)
1         Name 1
          Description 1
2         Name 2
          Description 2
.         Name ...
          Description ...
3         Name 3
          Description ...`

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: You could probably do the concatenating in SQL when getting the data. Look for Multi-line in the documentation, if I remember correctly it involves using a Memo for the columns properties and setting the view's OptionView.RowAutoHeight. For bold and italic font style you could e.g. use the columns OnGetContentStyle event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the main problem is how to make the two lines with different textformats (bold and italic), cause making values concatenated and putting them into a multi-line inplace editor isn't so difficult.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I missed that you already have archieved parts of what you desire. Have you tried using RichEditProperties as column's properties? I don't believe using a CustomDraw event is the way to go, drawing parts of multi-line Text in different styles might be archievable, but to be inline with the underlying Design you would need to be able to properly calculate the ViewInfo. RichEdit is the what comes first to my mind being able to have your desired style capabilities.

Comment: Do you rule out using a banded table-view? This would allow you to arrange columns to multiple rows.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried both possibilities suggested in comments, i.e. using custom drawing in
a standard DBTableView and using a DBBandedTableView and neither seems to offer an
ideal solution out of the box.

Using a DBTableView quickly runs into the sand for a non-expert like me:

- Although it is straightforward to draw the `Description` text below the `Name` text,
  it is fraught with difficulties, like how to pick up the bounds of the `Name` cell
  while drawing the `Description` one and how to avoid the grid drawing a residual outline
  of what would have been the `Description` cell and header if the `Description` were drawn
  normally.

Using a DBBandedTableView seems to converge on a workable solution with far fewer details to
address.  Try the following:

- Add a ClientDataSet, `CDS1` to your form, add persistent fields to it for the ID, Name and Description fields.
- Add a DBBandedTableView to your cxGrid and connect it to `CDS1` using a TDataSource.
- Create two bands in it and give them captions `Band` and `Band2` for ease of reference.
- Create columns for the `ID`, `Name` and `Description` columns.  Set their `Properties` property
  to TextEdit.
- In the DBBandedTableView editor, add the `ID` column to `Band` and the `Name` and
  `Description` columns to `Band2` using to `BandIndex` sub-property of the columns'
  `Position` property.  Also set the `RowIndex` sub-property of the `Description` column
  to 1, to cause it to be positioned below the `Name` field.

Set up the form's code as shown below, compile and run.  As you can see, all the custom drawing code does is to set the font style of the Name and Description fields.

The result is maybe not quite as you've
specified, but I'll leave you to iron out the remaining details - if you get stuck, say so.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    CDS1ID: TAutoIncField;
    DS1: TDataSource;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    CDS1Name: TStringField;
    CDS1Description: TStringField;
    cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel;
    cxGrid1: TcxGrid;
    cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1: TcxGridDBBandedTableView;
    cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1ID: TcxGridDBBandedColumn;
    cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Name: TcxGridDBBandedColumn;
    cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Description: TcxGridDBBandedColumn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CustomDrawCell(
      Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
      AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
  protected
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

[...]

procedure TForm1.CustomDrawCell(Sender:
    TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo:
    TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
var
  ACol : TcxGridDBBandedColumn;
begin
  ACol := TcxGridDBBandedColumn(AViewInfo.Item);
  if ACol = cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Name then
    ACanvas.Font.Style := ACanvas.Font.Style + [fsBold]
  else
  if ACol = cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Description then
    ACanvas.Font.Style := ACanvas.Font.Style + [fsItalic];
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin

  CDS1.CreateDataSet;

  CDS1.InsertRecord([1, 'Name1', 'Description1']);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([2, 'Name12', 'Description2']);

  CDS1.First;

  cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1ID.PropertiesClassName := 'TcxTextEditProperties';
  cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1ID.OnCustomDrawCell := CustomDrawCell;

  cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Name.PropertiesClassName := 'TcxTextEditProperties';
  cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Name.OnCustomDrawCell := CustomDrawCell;

  cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Description.PropertiesClassName := 'TcxTextEditProperties';
  cxGrid1DBBandedTableView1Description.OnCustomDrawCell := CustomDrawCell;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for this step-by-step approach, but the result isn't so nice as expected, bye the way, there is a solution like yours but with 0 line coding, it's the implementation of the PREVIEW, so via these two properties <dbtableGridView>.Preview.Visible = True and <dbtableGridView>.Preview.Column = dbgvDESCRIPTION and using two cxStyleRepositry styles, the Bold one for the NAME column, and the Italic for the DESCRIPTION, this will give a result closer to yours !

Because of this, i think that the DBBandedTableView will never be a solution !

Comment: Fine, but in that case, why did you ask the question?

Comment: Because i want to find a solution using OnCustomDrawCell, and we must always learn newer things. This is Life

Comment: What I meant is that you would have wasted less of readers time if you had taken the trouble to mention in your q your "preview" method and explained why it doesn't satisfy your wishes.

Comment: For me its not a solution, did you never used the Preview option of the dbtablegridviews, records with preview and records without it, its not the same, the focus rectangle of them is not the same, records with preview option are more complicated to navigate than simple ones. I write codes to obtain MS Office like programs, and i think that there is no a such solution (or appearance) in excel.
Try it and you will see ! (and i'm not here to waste readers time) Ooops !

Comment: I'd use cxStyles instead of owner drawing.

Answer (score 1):

A CustomDrawCell looks like an awfully burdensome solution for such a simple task.

The ideal solution would be for the TCxGrid having HTML columns, so you would just show on them a calculated field such as (replacing [] by <>) :

> [html] [b] Name 1 [/b] [br] [i] Description 1 [/i] [/html]

The problem is that TCxGrid doesn't have HTML Columns, but as others have said, you have RichEdit Columns available. So you can also build this solution using RTF instead of HTML.

Use Word (or Write, on the Windows folder) to create a sample and look for the RTF representation of your text :

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang3082{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang10\b\f0\fs22 Name 1\par
\b0\i Description 1\i0\par
}
```

Now add a calculated field to your dataset returning this RTF representation of the formatted text that you want to show :

```
procedure TMyForm.MyQueryCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var FormattedText: string;
begin
  FormattedText := '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang3082{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}' + sLineBreak +
                   '\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang10\b\f0\fs22 ' +
                   Dataset.FieldByName('Name').AsString + '\par' + sLineBreak +
                   '\b0\i ' + Dataset.FieldByName('Description').AsString + '\i0\par' + sLineBreak +
                   '}';

  Dataset.FieldByName('FormattedText').Value := FormattedText;    
end;
```

Finally you just need to set the Properties of a Column as RichEdit, and binding this FormattedText to that column would give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with some difficulties, and with the help of someone, this is the perfect solution with the **OnCustomDraw** instead of using **BandedTableView**, **RichEditColumn** or the **Preview** approaches.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1NameCustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
Function VarToText(AVal: Variant): String;
Begin
If VarIsNull(AVal) 
  Then Result := ''
  Else Result := VarToStr(AVal);
End;
Var
  AValue1, AValue2: Variant;
  AText: String;
  ARect: TRect;
Begin
  ARect := AViewInfo.ClientBounds;
  AValue1 := Sender.DataController.Values[AViewInfo.GridRecord.Index, 
  cxGrid1DBTableView1NAME.Index];
  AValue2 := Sender.DataController.Values[AViewInfo.GridRecord.Index, 
  cxGrid1DBTableView1DESCRIPTION.Index];
  ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  If VarIsNull(AValue1) 
    Then Begin
           AText := VarToText(AValue2);
           ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsItalic];
           ACanvas.DrawTexT(AText, ARect, taLeftJustify, vaCenter, True, 
                            False);
         End
    Else If VarIsNull(AValue2) 
      Then Begin
             AText := VarToText(AValue1);
             ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
             ACanvas.DrawTexT(AText, ARect, taLeftJustify, vaCenter, True, 
                              False);
           End
      Else Begin
             ACanvas.DrawTexT(VarToText(AValue1), ARect, taLeftJustify, 
                              vaTop, True, false);
             ARect.Top := ARect.Top + 
             ACanvas.TextHeight(VarToText(AValue1));

             ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsItalic];
             ACanvas.DrawTexT(VarToText(AValue2), ARect, taLeftJustify,               
             vaBottom, True, False);
           End;
  ADone := True;
end;
```

And, I'm here for any clarification.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot how this looks? I am seeing some issues when trying your code: do you change the Height for data Cells, setting View's OptionsView.DataRowHeight to a somehow defined value? Else, when the grid decides the name column gets the two texts drawn on top of each other. Selected rows don't show anything in the name column. When using a PopupMenu and either 'Best Fit' on the name column or 'Best Fit (all columns)' this does only fit for the original column text. Resizing the name column lets the drawn test look strange.

Comment: First, my apologizes for this late reply,
1. No, don't change the height of rows, you have to let it with it's default value (0).
2. You assign the cell value with two strings in any event such as double clicking in another grid.
3.Drawing the value of a cell with different font formats must be in the OnCustomDrawCell event.
This is a screenshot
https://www.4shared.com/s/flz2TYm91ca